# Is a tight concrete bound for the error-term in the prime-number-theorem known?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

Here :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem

it is mentioned that

$$\pi(x)=Li(x)+O(xe^{-a\sqrt{ln(x)}})$$

> What is a tight upper bound for $|\pi(x)-Li(x)|$ in concrete terms ?

The page mentions a concrete upper bound for the error-term assuming the Riemann-hypothesis, but I did not find such a bound which holds even if the Riemann-hypothesis is false.

Comment: A *tight* upper bound would probably settle the Riemann hypothesis!

Comment: The given bound is tight enough, but I am looking for a more concrete error-bound.

Comment: you mean the $\mathcal{O}$ constant, and the $x_0$ for which it is true ? see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/219733/quantitative-and-elementary-proofs-of-the-prime-number-theorem if you like such problems

Comment: The bound is given in O-notation and additionally contains the constant $a$ , which is not given concretely. It is only said that there is some $a$, such that the equation holds.

Comment: it is not given because : finding the effective constants can be very hard, and also almost nobody cares, except the people who work at improving those bounds, and they are often improved, and all the different bounds are useful in some different context (if $x$ is large or small, if you are interested in $\pi(x) - \pi(x/2)$, or $\pi(x)-\pi(\sqrt{x})$, or  $\pi(x)$ for  $x\in (N,N+\sqrt{N})$, etc.)

Comment: Perhaps [Rosser and Schoenfeld](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255631807) give what you want.

Comment: [Updating the error term in the prime number theorem by 
Tim Trudgian](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.2689) is a recent paper on the subject. It contains varied information along the lines you ask about. It might be simplest you browse this; there are various trade off to be made and it is not quite clear which ones you are willing to make.